# .htaccess redirect www to non-www with SSL/HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've got several domains operating under a single `.htaccess` file, each having an SSL certificate.

I need to force a `https` prefix on every domain while also ensuring `www` versions redirect to `no-www` ones.

Below is my code; it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.%{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I want to achieve is to: redirect something like `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve it?

Comment: Hope this helps, it also explains which is best for SEO too. https://wpza.net/redirect-wordpress-to-https-using-htaccess-file/

Answer (score 116):

**www to non www with https**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]" was changed to "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]" (by @KenVerhaegen) otherwise "it would first redirect to non-http, and then to https... so now we can avoid the possibly triggered second redirect."

Comment: Really simple and match, this should also the right answer for [*this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467329/htaccess-force-https-and-redirect-www-to-non-www-but-no-other-subdomains)

Comment: no matter what i try, it doesnt work for Safari and Firefox. Chrome is ok. any solution would help - i have certificate only for https://example.com - not for https://www.example.com

Comment: @KalpeshPopat: This was probably because your browser cache kept the info where to go when you enter the URL. As soon as the DNS/browser cache update, it will work.

Comment: is this answer working in 2021? I tried but I am getting the error "The page isn’t redirecting properly" in firefox.

Answer (score 62):

Ref: [Apache redirect www to non-www and HTTP to HTTPS](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-apache/)

> http://example.com
>
> http://www.example.com
>
> https://www.example.com
>
> to
>
> https://example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

If instead of [example.com](http://example.com) you want the default URL to be [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), then simply change the third and the fifth lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: For redirecting to Non-WWW URL with HTTPS this answer with the first section is absolutely perfect and works fine for me.

Comment: After this many years still your answer is charm.

Comment: This worked. But make sure this is on the top of your .htaccess file and not below, because other code may overwrite it.

Comment: It won't redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com

Comment: Where should i add my domain name in this code : RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]. What is the meaning for %1 and {REQUEST_URI}?

Comment: not working if domain has some request after .com 
example https://www.sample.com/products
how to make it work for it?

Comment: While this does work for me, it makes two redirects... and for some reason the first of those two is always a 302 redirect. This is considered an error in SEO tools like SEMRush. Does anyone know how to overcome that first 302 redirect that this code seems to trigger?

Answer (score 23):

Your condition will never be true, because its like "if (a == a + b)".

I'd try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will capture "google.com" from "www.google.com" into %1, the rest in $1 and after that combining the 2, when HTTP_HOST starts with www (with or without https).

Comment: Unfortunately this still creates a "Connection is Untrusted" error when someone tries to access https://www.domain.com

Comment: Hmm but it is redirecting properly? If it is it might be a certificate issue.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10726167/372643) for the certificate issue.

Comment: RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L] wasn't working for me. if I went to http://www.mysite.com/some/path it was redirecting to just http://mysite.com if you change this to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L] (note the brackets) then it redirects as expected to http://mysite.com/some/path

Answer (score 16):

To enforce **non-www** and **https** in a single request, you can use the following Rule in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

This redirects **http://www.example.com/** or **https://www.example.com/** to ssl non-www **https://example.com/** .

I am using **R** Temp Redirect flag for testing purpose and to avoid browser caching. If you want to make the redirect permanent , just change the **R** flag to **R=301** .

Comment: hmm but still when I enter site with www safari says that the page is insecure and opera does not want to redirect any option with or without www to ssl, why?

Comment: this is giving too many redirects

Comment: @user151496 Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: of course i did that

Comment: @user151496 This code works perfactly fine on apache server. Are you sure you are not using any load balancing or proxy server like Cloudflare? If you are using CloudFlare then this wont work. Please confirm.

Comment: no, it's a regular apache server on a regular vps, no cloudflares or load balancers. actual server running apache `2.4.38` and the above code gives too many redirects. i have one server where it works and on this one it doesn't. the commands that worked on this particular server were: `
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]`

Comment: i think your one didn't work because {HTTPS} is not available on all servers, that one supported `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` instead

Comment: @user151496 yes, thats because you are using a proxy server. `{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` is a  variable its used to test URL scheme on proxy  .

Answer (score 10):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

This works for me perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 5):

Certificate must cover both www and non-www https. Some provider's certs cover both for www.xxxx.yyy, but only one for xxxx.yyy.

Turn on rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Make all http use https:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xxx.yyy/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make only www https use the non-www https:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www[.].+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xxxx.yyy/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Cannot be processing non-www https, otherwise a loop occurs.

In [L,R=301]:

1. L = If the rule was processed, don't process any more.
2. R=301 = Tells browser/robot to do a permanent redirect.

**More generic**

A more generic approach -- not port-dependant -- is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xxxx.yyy/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

to make any url with `www` drop it.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !1
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xxxx.yyy/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

to force any non-https url, even for those system downstream from load-balancers that drop https, use https.

Note that I have not tested the `forwarded` options, so would appreciate feedback on any issues with them. Those lines could be left out if your system is not behind a load-balancer.

**TO HTTP_HOST or not**

You can use `${HTTP_HOST}` to be part of the URL in the `RewriteRule`, or you can use your explicit canonical domain name text (`xxxx.yyy` above).

Specifying the domain name explicitly ensures that no slight-of-hand character-bending means are used in the user-supplied URL to possibly trick your site into doing something it might not be prepared for, or at least ensures that the proper domain name appears in the address bar, regardless of which URL string opened the page.

It might even help convert punycode-encoded domains to show the proper unicode characters in the address bar.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This worked for me after much trial and error.  Part one is from the user above and will capture www.xxx.yyy and send to https://xxx.yyy

Part 2 looks at entered URL and checks if HTTPS, if not, it sends to HTTPS

Done in this order, it follows logic and no error occurs.

HERE is my FULL version in side htaccess with WordPress:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

To me was better hardcoding "example.com" as string, so I need less rules, even you can use it to redirect from .org to .com or similar too:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</IfModule>
```