# Redirect https to non-www and http to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, no-www

I need a combination of redirects to achieve the following:

To redirect `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com`, while redirecting `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`.

I would like to force the `www` prefix do the domain name when the site is accessed over `http`.

However the SSL certificate only works without the `www`.

When accessed over `https`, I don't want the domain name to have the `www` prefix.

Comment: Why on earth would you want that?

Comment: Because the ssl certificate is setup for just "mysite.com"

Comment: Then, why not also redirect http traffic to the none-www version?

Answer (score 13):

The redirection from `https://www.mysite.com` to `https://mysite.com` can only happen after the client has made an initial request to `https://www.mysite.com`.

For this initial connection to work, the server at `https://www.mysite.com` must have a certificate valid for `www.mysite.com`, otherwise, this connection won't even happen (and the server won't send a redirection response).

If you still want a redirection, on the same server, your server must present a certificate that is valid for the host names you want to serve. You should get a certificate with two Subject Alternative Name DNS entries: `mysite.com` and `www.mysite.com`; this will allow you to serve both hosts with the same certificate (and then use the rewrite rules if needed).

(You could also use Server Name Indication with two distinct certificates, if you expect the clients to support it, but that's usually for completely different host names.)

It's quite common for CAs to issue certificates that are valid for both `mysite.com` and `www.mysite.com` when you apply for one of the other, sometimes without an extra fee.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess file in your **non-HTTPS** document root:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R]
```

And this in your HTTPS document root:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [R]
```

Comment: Neither is working? Are you sure your .htaccess files are being read?

Comment: After further testing, yes, the first is working. `http://mysite.com` is redirected to `http://www.mysite.com` But `https://www.mysite.com` is not redirected to `https://mysite.com`

Comment: Further testing... I added both of these, just realized https is redirecting to http.