# Redirect non-www http request www domain with https connection

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, apache2

I want to redirect `http://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`. I succeeded in redirecting `http` to `https` like this (in `default-ssl.conf` file):

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
  RewriteEngine on 
  ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  RewriteEngine on 
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
  ServerName domain.com:443 
  ServerAlias www.domain.com 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I type my domain without `www`, I get the error message `This site is untrusted, the certificate is only valid to <www.domain.com>`

I tried many proposed solutions on the web but it did not work.
My environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Apache2
- SSL issued for <"www.domain.com"> (common name)

Comment: am not sure why I got down vote, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess this was downvoted because you probably didn't look hard enough for an existing answer to this. If you search this site (top right of the page) for "www non-www certificate redirect" (or even Google), you find a number of very similar question (if not exact duplicates), in particular [this one, as the first result](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10726167/372643), which, although not strictly an exact duplicate, has an answer that tells you exactly why you're getting this certificate error message.

Comment: It is totally fine mate :) but believe me I searched for an answer the last 3 days, the answer I found here was the only one that worked. It might help some one else in the future, who knows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `http` (pot 80) config:

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
  RewriteEngine on 
  ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

To this which would do a combined check for `https` and `www`:

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
  RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

That said, you still might get the `This site is untrusted, the certificate is only valid to <www.domain.com>` since the initial connection will be to the incorrect certificate hostname. So it might be better to do this with both configs—`http` and `https`—adjusted like this:

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
  RewriteEngine on 
  ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
  ServerName domain.com:443 
  ServerAlias www.domain.com 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(.+)
  RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The idea being that on the `http` connection you simply redirect to `https`. Then on the `https` connection, you check if `www` is set & adjust accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the reply mate. unfortunately it did not work. now it redirects www to non-www, even when I put <www.domain.com> it redirects to (https://domain.com).
Maybe if you inverse the rule it will work (sorry I have no clue how to inverse the condition rule, I am not used to this type of coding XD)

thanks

Comment: now It works! I just added '!' before ^www... 
Thank you very much my friend!  Only one thing remained buggy is: when I type https:// domain .com without "www" = it gives untrusted link warning. any solutions for that case?  
thanks

Comment: Make sense, Appreciate your explanation. maybe I will buy different certificate in future that support both www and non-www.