# codeigniter "No direct script access allowed"

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

even i have added "if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); " on top of controller .Actually I need to display data in div 
my ajax call:
below is ajax call which calls Createcaptcha to get data but instead of data it response "No direct script access allowed"

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'website/Createcaptcha',
            success: function(data){
                $("#captcha").html(data); 
            }
        });

    });
```

below is controller

```
 public function Createcaptcha(){               
        $image = $this->captcha_model->create_image();
  echo $image;

    }
```

Response data is displayed in div as "No direct script access allowed" ,
It works fine on  xampp localhost

Comment: what is website/Createcaptcha? is it a controller named website with a function called Createcaptcha?

Comment: Yes website is a controller and Createcaptcha is a function

Comment: Even if  I delete everything from Createcaptcha function and just / echo "hello" / it returns the same response I.e  no direct script access allowed

Comment: Is your website controller extending CI_Controller?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your BASEPATH is set in codeigniter. It is set in index.php of root folder. Just echo the BASEPATH and see what it is printed.

Find the following in index.php

```
define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `<?` with `<?php` and everything worked fine because of php settings in server.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

in **database.php** file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and for someone who might look for an answer for this issue, my ten cents.

In basepath website name is set as htts://www.websitename.com and client opened without https (http://www.websitename.com) and also in some cases without www (https://websitename.com or http://websitename.com).

Since either of them do not match to the basepath defined, the request is not honored as ajax request. 
Solution : ensure that you have proper redirection (http to https & non-www to www).

[https & www redirecting answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https)

Answer (score -1):

In my case project path(base URL) was wrong.