# Redirect to https and www in single redirect in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I want to redirect following domains

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
```

to

```
https://www.example.com
```

in a single http request

I know it can be done in two requests using

```
#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but and extra redirect increases loadtime of page.

I want to do both things in one http request

I am using apache2 on ubuntu

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect to https and www in a single http request, you can use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: working flawlessly... have to add these lines both to secure and normal vhost config

Comment: @amit-verma how would I do the same if the site works on `https://example.com`?

Comment: @bugnumber see my answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https/42653862#42653862