# htaccess: Multiple transformations in a single redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to do those classical 301 redirects:

- Prepend "www" if there is not.
- Add "/shop/" directory if there is not.
- In both cases, I want to mantain the file requested and possible parameters.

And also (this is the point) I want to avoid multiple redirects when http://myhost.com is requested:

1. 301 -> http://www.myhost.com
2. 301 -> http://www.myhost.com/shop/

I want only 1 redirect. How can I do it in the simplest way?

Comment: Maybe this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/38901066/1741542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1/shop%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```