# htaccess not redirecting BOTH www AND https to non-www AND https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have searched S.O. over and found quite a few answers but none that address this single problem!

I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Both `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost *:443>` are pointing to the same

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html
```

**WHAT WORKS**

```
http://example.com        -> https://example.com
http://www.example.com    -> https://example.com
```

**WHAT DOESN'T WORK**

```
https://www.example.com   -> https://example.com
```

Why if *both* conditions are set, this fails?  This comes directly from [THIS PROTECTED S.O. QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https)

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: How is your SSL site setup? Does it have same `DocumentRoot` path in `VirtualHost`?

Comment: Good question ... Yes it does.   I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my virtual hosts, I needed to add the `ServerAlias` of `www`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
```