# How do I 301 redirect multiple domains to a SSL CloudFront distribution?

Tags: php, ssl, amazon-cloudfront

For example, Say I have the following site in CloudFront under SSL:

https://example.com

How do I 301 redirect a subdomain to it, eg:

www.example.com -> https://example.com

Also, how do I 301 redirect a completely different 'addon domain' to it, eg:

example2.com -> https://example.com

My origin is running PHP in Elastic Beanstalk and I've tried adding rules to my .htaccess file but with no success.

Comment: Show us your rules that failed.

Comment: There are many answers to this question, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https