# Apache2 redirect to non-www

Tags: apache2

I am trying to setup an apache2 redirect from https://www.dolgins.com to https://dolgins.com and cannot get it working correctly. I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04) and have the A records pointed correctly.
Here is a screenshot of my apache config[image]
Here is my .htacess file located in the DocumentRoot folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas? Also, I want the URL to change. What would I need to do?

Thank you
Joseph

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]` `RewriteRule (.*) http://dolgins.com/$1 [R=301,L]` will this work?

Comment: I did not according to curl -I https://www.dolgins.com - there was no 301 redirect.

Comment: Are you sure? curl -I www.dolgins.com `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` `Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)` edit also same with curl -I dolgins.com

Comment: Not entirely, but I think you need to use the "https://". Then, there is no redirect and the "www" remains in the URL address box.

Comment: Will this answer work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28831015/7735711

Comment: It is not. I wonder if apache is finding my .htaccess file. any checks there?

Comment: Try a simple redirect and see if it works, if simple url redirection doesn't work either than apache won't find your .htaccess

Comment: That setup did not work either.what is a simple redirect?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` `Redirect 301 / https://google.com/` when you make this your .htaccess, and open your website does it redirect to google instead? If yes, something is wrong with htaccess if no, apache can't find/work .htaccess.

Comment: I was not redirected to Google, so apache2 is not finding my .htacess file

Comment: Yes, that's the current issue.

Comment: I have 2 config files: one dolgins_production-le-ssl.conf and one dolgins_production.conf. Which would should have the <directory>?

Comment: adding the <directory> ... </directory> to both the apache2 config files I have associated with the app achieved it! Originally, I had not put that code on the SSL config file. If you want to answer the question @TuğberkKaanDuman I will mark it as accepted!

Comment: It's fine, I'm glad that you managed to solve the problem @JoeD.